# Touch, open, ls not working on Mac 10.15.6 terminal, PATH issues

Tags: bash, macos

I have been trying to use touch, open and ls commands but this error is returned - `-bash: open: command not found`. It has always worked until today. This started happening after I added the Postgres path to PATH. Additionally, my PATH looks quite messy and I have absolutely no understanding of that.

Note - I have been through various solutions here on PATH and `bash command not found` but none seem to be working. Another thing is I can’t use stuff like `sudo`. I am adding my .bash_profile here if it helps -

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by ‘conda init’ !!

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH=“${PATH}”
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
export PATH
export PATH = /Users/arif/Library/Python/2.7/bin
export PATH = /Users/arif/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH
echo “source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh” >> ~/.bash_profilesource /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH


# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin(ScrapProj) Arifs-MacBook-Air:scraper_app arif$ python3
```

Please help me fix this, Thanks!

Comment: `“` and `"` are different characters and the former doesn't have a special meaning for bash, is that a typo?

Comment: @oguzismail i think it appears so because I copied, otherwise I checked my bash_profile. The characters are `"`

Comment: can you post your output of the command `echo $PATH`? anyway I think one of the problems is at the line that sets `PATH` to just python2.7 bin directory, this line `export PATH = /Users/arif/Library/Python/2.7/bin` should be removed, since it overwrites the previous contents of the `PATH`

Comment: @MarcoLucidi so this was the output of `echo $PATH` earlier - `/Users/arif/newcoderProjects/scrape/ScrapProj/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`.  Then I got the following error - ```Last login: Sun Aug  2 12:49:48 on console
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/arif/Library/Python/2.7/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/arif/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier```

Comment: @MarcoLucidi also this is the current output echo $PATH - `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`

Comment: @ArifKhan your `PATH` is missing `/bin:/usr/bin` and friends and contains only  Postgres bin directory. I'll try to fix your `.bash_profile` and post it as an answer...

Comment: @MarcoLucidi one question(might be dumb, please forgive) - isn't python 2.7 a default requirement in MacOS for a number of processes(read that somewhere, when trying to figure out whether I could run python2 and python3 simultaneously)? Also, thanks for the help.

Comment: @ArifKhan yes, I think `python` is a dependency for lots of tools in modern unix-like systems and I guess a default version is already installed in macos, maybe under `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the contents of your `PATH` gets overwritten because the "previous" `PATH` is not (always) added back when you put a new directory. that is why you end up with just Postgres bin directory at the end and the basic unix tools (`ls`, `touch`, etc..) cannot be found.

I tried to fix the issues in your `.bash_profile`:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

# these should already be in the PATH, but re-adding them wont hurt...
export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH"

# add other directories to the PATH here remembering to append (previous) PATH at the end
PATH="/Users/arif/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"

echo “source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh” >> ~/.bash_profilesource /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: works now, thanks a ton. Also, thanks for the comments, now I know how to add new directories to the PATH without messing it up.